# If I use Windows bootloader (by easybcd) instead of grub in dual boot, will it be enough just to delete linux partition for completely removing linux?

Tags: linux, windows, grub, bootloader

I am using dual booting of Windows 10 and Kali linux. I have GRUB to switch between them. I know that only formating the Linux partition isn't enough to remove it. I need to remove GRUB too by using recovery disc. But if I'm not using GRUB but windows bootloader (changed by easybcd), will it be enough to just to format Linux partition?

Answer (score 0):

Once Windows is booting without using GRUB, there is no need to
format the Linux partition.

Just delete it so that it becomes unallocated space that can be used
for installing another operating system, or that can be merged with
another partition (if one exists on the same disk).

---

To restore the Windows 10 bootloader follow these steps:

- Log into Windows 10
- Open a Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Run the commands

  ```
    bootrec /fixmbr
    bootrec /fixboot
    bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr /force
  ```

For more help about bootsect command see
[Bootsect Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options).

Note: Before doing anything, ensure you have backups for your
data and create a Windows 10 boot media, in case of emergency.
If you lose the ability to boot the computer,
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Won't I face any boot issue? I fear a "grub rescue" error may appear.

Comment: I thought you were already booting into Windows without using GRUB. Is this not the case? Does your computer use UEFI or BIOS? Which version of Windows?

Comment: Yep, I've already mentioned that I am using windows 10 and still using grub. But I want to switch to windows bootloader. I need to know how to delete linux completely if I switch to that.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? This is crucial information.

Comment: BIOS/Legacy Mode

Comment: I added more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last query- why do I need to restore bootloader as I'll already have obtained it via EasyBCD? I'm giving a [YouTube link](https://youtu.be/GaCbTe1eEes) on this regard

Comment: EasyBCD will also work. The above commands are in case it didn't work and you find yourself unable to boot, you could then boot into the Command Prompt and execute them.